# when are includes processed for static functions?

Tags: php

Consider the following:

```
class MyClass { 
    public static function MyIncludingMethod() {
        include_once("includes.php");
    }

    public static function MyOtherMethod() {
    }
}
```

Assuming this is valid- when will includes.php be included?

Option 1) When the php file containing all of this is included

Option 2) When MyClass::MyIncludingMethod() is called

Option 3) When anything from MyClass is called, even if MyClass::MyIncludingMethod() has not been called

Comment: This should be fairly easy for you to test. Try it, you'll learn something.

Comment: Put inside of `includes.php` something like `touch('i_was_called.txt');` and check it )

Comment: Yes, and typing "1", "2", or "3" would have been faster than what y'all wrote. This was not a question about how to learn by testing, thank you.

Comment: Programming might not be for you if _learning by testing_ isn't your style.....

Comment: @Crackertastic - this site might not be for you if *learning by testing* is your only style :P

Comment: You know @davidkomer you could have tested this and it would have been faster than asking the question in the first place. You could have saved everyone, especially yourself, a lot of time. Just sayin' ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No- for the next person looking for this question, it will be faster to see the question and answer than not see the question (which I wouldn't have written if I subscribed to the "just test it" idea)

Comment: @davidkomer we seem to be mistaking your magnanimous improvement of the state of internet knowledge with outright laziness. Please accept our *sincerest* apologies.

Comment: @davidkomer I don't come here to have folks test my stuff for me ;)  And I doubt anyone will look for this question since their first instinct will be: _"I outta try that out!"_

Comment: It's not "laziness". My experience programming (going on 10 years as a paid professional, more than that as a hobbyist) tells me that people who really know a language inside and out can often point at gotchas that wouldn't be apparent otherwise. Maybe include_once works differently on different OS's for example, I don't know- I'm not an expert at PHP. Seeing a definitive answer from someone who does know reveals a lot more than my test would, and it's a valuable resource for others. Those reasons combined are why I would rather see an answer from the community than myself. Is that lazy?

Comment: @Crackertastic - you and your assumptions are more important than me and my assumptions. I understand

Comment: But fine, since I'm in the minority here and everyone else thinks that easily testable questions should not be posed on SO, even if those tests are not comprehensive, I'll close it.

Comment: It has less to do with assumptions and more to do with folks on SO expecting those asking questions to have put some effort into the topic they are inquiring.  Don't take it personal.  A better question would have been: _"I have ran the following code with includes: ..[show snippet].. I am unsure if includes are processed at compile time, or at runtime during script execution.  Does anyone know?"_

Comment: That's a silly waste of time in this case, even if it is a community rule. Since it is though, I understand and will humbly bow down to it

Comment: The majority of people think it should be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

includes.php:

```
<?php
  touch('i_was_called.txt');
?>
```

Results

1. No
2. Yes
3. No

Everything is as expected :)